# ¿Cómo Crear un ComboBox en Python con PyQt5 en el cual sus valores dependan de la selección de otro ComboBox?

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt5

Estoy usando Python 3.4 y PyQt5 para crear 2 combo Box.
En el Primero se muestra una lista de marcas de productos. Esta lista la lleno por medio de un archivo marcas.csv.
En el segundo Combo Box se muestra una lista de Productos los cuales se obtienen de un archivo productos.csv. Este archivo contiene una columna que incluye la marca a la que pertenece cada producto.

El objetivo es que cuando el usuario seleccione una marca del primer combo Box el segundo automáticamente se rellene solamente con los productos de la marca previamente elegida.

Ya hice un primer intento con listas pre-definidas, lo cual funciona bien cuando los datos en ambos Combo Box no cambian, sin embargo, en este caso particular tanto la lista de marcas como la de productos son constantemente modificadas por lo que trabajar con listas pre-definidas no es funcional. Tendría que crear cientos de listas una para cada marca con todos los productos que contiene y estas modificarlas cada que alguna de las dos listas cambie.

¿Me podrían dar ideas de como resolver este problema? Es decir filtrar el segundo combo Box de acuerdo a la selección del primero.

Como referencia, para mi primer intento tomé como base el código del blog 
http://www.pythondiario.com/2015/03/combinar-2-combobox-en-pyqt-python.html

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# www.pythondiario.com
# Combinar 2 ComboBox

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

# Cargar nuestro archivo .ui
form_class = uic.loadUiType("combobox.ui")[0]

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
  QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
  self.setupUi(self)
  #Rellana los datos por primera ves del comboBox_2
  self.llenar_comboBox2()
  #Señal para cambiar, segun la selecccion, el comboBox_2
  QtCore.QObject.connect(self.comboBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(QString)"), self.llenar_comboBox2)                         
  self.btn_Ver.clicked.connect(self.btn_Ver_clicked)



 # Evento del boton Ver
 def btn_Ver_clicked(self):

  x = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
  self.Resultado.setText(x)

 # Llena el comboBox_2
 def llenar_comboBox2(self):

  python = ["Diego", "Martin", "Lorena"]
  java = ["Sergio", "Maria", "Miguel"]

  self.comboBox_2.clear()
  if self.comboBox.currentText() == "Python":
   self.comboBox_2.addItems(python)
  elif self.comboBox.currentText() == "Java":
   self.comboBox_2.addItems(java)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 MyWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
 MyWindow.show()
 app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo normal en estos casos es usar un diccionario en el que las claves sean las marcas y los valores una lista con los modelos. Este diccionario puede ser cargado al inicio desde el csv y puede ser modificado sin problemas en tiempo de ejecución añadiendo una nueva pareja `clave: valor` y actualizando el el primer `QCombobox`.

Dejo un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ejemplo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.marcas = {"Alfa Romeo": ["MiTo", "Giulietta", "4C"], 
                       "Aston Martin": ["DB9", "Rapide", "Vanquish"],
                       "Audi": ["A1", "A3", "A4"]
                      }
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Comboxs enlazados')
        self.setGeometry(0,  0, 600, 400)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        lb_mar = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, text = "Marca")
        lb_mod = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, text = "Modelo")
        self.combo_mar = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_mod = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        layout.addWidget(lb_mar, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(lb_mod, 0, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_mar, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_mod, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.combo_mar.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.llenar_comboBox_modelos)
        self.llenar_comboBox_marcas()
        self.show()   

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()      
    def llenar_comboBox_marcas(self):
        self.combo_mar.clear()
        self.combo_mar.addItems(sorted(self.marcas.keys()))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)    
    def llenar_comboBox_modelos(self,  marca):
        self.combo_mod.clear()
        self.combo_mod.addItems(self.marcas[marca])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ejemplo()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

El diccionario se puede crear desde un csv sin problemas, por ejemplo:

**marcas.csv**

> Marca,Modelo
>   Alfa Romeo,MiTo
>   Alfa Romeo,Giulietta
>   Alfa Romeo,4C
>   Aston Martin,DB9
>   Aston Martin,Rapide
>   Aston Martin,Vanquish
>   Audi,A1
>   Audi,A3
>   Audi,A4

**main.py:**

```
import collections
import csv
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ejemplo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.marcas = {"Sin datos": ["Sin datos"]}
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Comboxs enlazados')
        self.setGeometry(0,  0, 600, 400)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 0)
        lb_mar = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, text = "Marca")
        lb_mod = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, text = "Modelo")
        self.combo_mar = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_mod = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        layout.addWidget(lb_mar, 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(lb_mod, 0, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_mar, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_mod, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.combo_mar.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.llenar_comboBox_modelos)
        self.cargar_marcas_csv()
        self.show()        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def llenar_comboBox_marcas(self):
        self.combo_mar.clear()
        self.combo_mar.addItems(sorted(self.marcas.keys()))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)    
    def llenar_comboBox_modelos(self,  marca):
        self.combo_mod.clear()
        self.combo_mod.addItems(self.marcas[marca])

    def cargar_marcas_csv(self):
        try:
            with open("marcas.csv") as f:
                reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
                data = collections.defaultdict(list)
                for row in reader:
                    data[row["Marca"]].append(row["Modelo"])
            self.marcas = dict(data)
        except:
            print("Error: No se pudo cargar el fichero csv")
        self.llenar_comboBox_marcas()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ejemplo()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias. Lo probaré en poco tiempo.

Comment: @AlejandroGomez he añadido un pequeño  ejemplo simple con un csv también por si te interesa. Cualquier duda comenta. Un saludo.

Comment: GRACIAS. @FJSevilla es exactamente lo que necesito, ya lo probé y funciona excelente.